# Is there a way to have printf() properly print out an array (of floats, say)?

Tags: c, printf

I believe I have carefully read the entire `printf()` documentation but could not find any way to have it print out, say, the elements of a 10-element array of `float(s)`.

E.g., if I have

```
float[] foo = {1., 2., 3., ..., 10.};
```

Then I'd like to have a single statement such as

```
printf("what_do_I_put_here\n", foo);
```

Which would print out something along the lines of:

```
1. 2. 3. .... 10.
```

Is there a way to do that in vanilla C?

Comment: I use something like `#define printarr(fmt, dat, len) for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) printf(fmt, dat[i])` and then call it with `printarr("%.2f ", foo, (sizeof(foo) / sizeof(float)));`

Answer (score 31, accepted):

you need to iterate through the array's elements

```
float foo[] = {1, 2, 3, 10};
int i;
for (i=0;i < (sizeof (foo) /sizeof (foo[0]));i++) {
    printf("%lf\n",foo[i]);
}
```

or create a function that returns stacked sn `printf` and then prints it with

```
printf("%s\n",function_that_makes_pretty_output(foo))
```

Answer (score 9):

You have to loop through the array and `printf()` each element:

```
for(int i=0;i<10;++i) {
  printf("%.2f ", foo[i]);
}

printf("\n");
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to go for a loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(foo) / sizeof(float); ++i)
   printf("%f", foo[i]);
printf("\n");
```

Comment: In Fortran it is possible to use an implied do loop. `write(*,'(3d 3d 3d)')(i,i=1,12)` would print 4 lines containing the digits from 1 to 12, 3 digit per line. Where each digit would take 3 characters long when printed. Is there a C equivalent for doing this?

Comment: It looks like in the loop, just use < sizeof(foo) is not enough. It prints more elements than expected. But i < sizeof(foo) / sizeof(float) does the trick. Thanks.

Comment: Did you try this? The numbers are printed with no separation, so unreadable.
I think it's also common practice to write sizeof(foo) / sizeof(foo[0]) so if somebody someday changes the array from float to double for example, your length calculation still works. I usually just define a LENGTH(a) macro.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a way to print array for you in printf. "printf" function has no idea how long your array is.

Comment: That could be specified in the format. But I don't think any such specifier exists.

Answer (score -3):

To be Honest All Are good but it will be easy if or more efficient if someone use n time numbers and show them in out put.so prefer this will be a good option. Do not predefined array variable let user define and show the result. Like this..

```
int main()
{
    int i,j,n,t;
int arry[100];
    scanf("%d",&n);
   for (i=0;i<n;i++)
   { scanf("%d",&t);
       arry[i]=t;
   }
for(j=0;j<n;j++)
    printf("%d",arry[j]);

return 0;
}
```